# SQL Lead and Lag in a View w/o Order By?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I understand that SQL Views should not have an ORDER BY statement with a SELECT TOP 100 Percent added in as a hack to get the ORDER BY to work.

But how then might we get the LEAD() and LAG() functions to work with a SQL View if we cannot use ORDER BY? When the very row order is imperative for LEAD() and LAG() to work properly?

Comment: You use the `ORDER BY` within the _window function_ nor for the complete result.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use LAG or LEAD, you supply an ORDER BY in the OVER() part of the column definition.

This only affects how the LAG or LEAD is determined, and does nothing to affect the ORDER of the results of the query.